# htaccess rewrite if url doesnt have a query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I have a htaccess that rewrites to **/login** if conditions aren't met.
It's working fine for urls without query_string.

However I have no clue how to include **/reset?query_string** to accepted conditions. And want to exclude **/reset**

**/reset?6tdsBMxpeeJEDUvYzwKmLzIusLYLjgMtIj**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forgotten$

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /login [R=301,L,QSD]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /login [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your .htaccess that excludes `/reset?query`:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# /reset with query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^(reset)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(forgotten|login)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ /login [R=301,L,QSD]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following htaccess rules file. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Also I am making use of apache's variable named `THE_REQUEST` by which we can handle both uri as well as query string.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
##Rules for handling rest uri without query string.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ 
RewriteRule ^reset/?$ /login? [R=301,L,NC]

##Rules for reset with uri and query string.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/reset\?\S+\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /reset? [R=301,NC]

##Rule for login page's backend rewrite.
RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [QSA,NC,L]

##Rule for forgotten page's backend rewrite.
RewriteRule ^forgotten/?$ forgotten.php [QSA,NC,L]

##Rules for non-existing pages should be served with index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I tried it, it's nog working. Changed the code a bit to give more inside.

Comment: http://localhost/reset?6tdsBMxpeeJEDUvYzwKmLzIusLYLjgMtIj

Comment: It breaks the conditions

Comment: Still breaking. I think on \s. Only login works everthing else 'File not found'. I can use a hack if page is /reset and has no query then redirect in php. However I want to catch it in the first stage in htaccess. appreciate the help mate

Comment: @DataConnect, so what I understood is, is uri is like `http://localhost:8080/` OR `http://localhost:8080/login` OR `http://localhost:8080/forgotten` OR `http://loalhost:80/reset?blabla` then it should go to `/login` these rules handle these, let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245562/discussion-between-dataconnect-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: I will try to explain; I have index.php thats my base. There I have login.php forgotten.php and reset.php. My goal is to exclude reset.php without a query so when someone types /reset the page needs to redirect to /login or else if it has a query /reset?12345 then stays its ok. The / will auto redirect to /login its all working as expected except for /reset?1234 I have no clue to exclude /reset and only accept /reset?1234

Comment: @DataConnect, I have changed the rules now, could you please do check them once and let me know how it goes, cheers.